# Error while loading data from BigQuery table to Dataproc cluster

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm new to Dataproc and PySpark and facing certain issues while integrating BigQuery table to Dataproc cluster via Jupyter Lab API. Below is the code that I used for loading BigQuery table to the Dataproc cluster through Jupyter Notebook API but I am getting an error while loading the table

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

 SparkSession.builder.appName('Jupyter BigQuery Storage').config(
  'spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar').getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery").option(
  "table", "publicdata.samples.shakespeare").load()

df.printSchema()
```

Below, is the error I'm getting

````
Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-789ad67053e5> in <module>()
      1 table = "publicdata.samples.shakespeare"
----> 2 df = spark.read.format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery").option("table",table).load()
      3 df.printSchema()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.pyc in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    170             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    171         else:
--> 172             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    173 
    174     @since(1.4)

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o254.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:622)
    ... 13 more```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please assign the `SparkSession.builder` result to a variable:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .appName('Jupyter BigQuery Storage')\
  .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar')\
  .getOrCreate()
```

Also, the reference to the public datasets is  `bigquery-public-data`, so please change the reading to

```
df = spark.read.format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery")\
  .option("table", "bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare")\
  .load()
```

Comment: I also changed the format to ```format("bigquery")```